# How to implement cloud computing and generate token in php?

Tags: php, sockets, cloud, project, token

I wanted to do a cloud computing project in php. The project is that users will store their files in cloud server and if there is any manipulation in their files without their knowledge, then it should detect and correct it.. 
My question is that how can i implement this in php???

In base paper it is given that we should generate tokens for each file in server, and while detecting we can use that token to verify..

I didn't use socket programming.. Suggest me how to do pls...

Comment: i created 4 folders naming cloudserver1,2,3,4.. and i stored the files uploaded by user. and then the user can download these files or delete it.. this is all i done and it is one module. the other module is detection.. i doubt wat is cloudserver and how can i implement in php.. is this enough or wil my professors expect very network orientedly..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to know if a file as been modified or altered is to save a has copy of that file

```
$file = "name.pdf" ;
$md5 = md5_file($file);
$sha1 = sha1_file($file);
```

Save a copy og each has in a database with the file name ... always check with the hash every time you need to verify or retrieve the file ... you would know if it has been illegally modified

Automatically correcting the file ... you can also save a backup copy on a CDN hosting and only retrieve it to replace the existing one if it has been modified or tampered with.

Another option is last modification date .. but that can be tricked ..

Let me know if this helps

Thanks
:)

Comment: so if the hash is not matching it means it is modified, so i can correct it with backup copy. isn't it??? and thanks a lot i got some idea... in base paper, it is given that we should store the files in the server with parity bits. is it possible

Comment: i am only doing my final year project.. i think cdn hosting will not be necessary.. i am storing my files in my local system.. Can i store my backup copy also in local system?

Comment: A local back up is a good idea ....  Yes if the hash does not match .. it means the file has been modified ....

Comment: I want the coding of cloud server and client... pls help for my college project..

Comment: what do you mean cloud server and client ?? explain more

Comment: wat i explained above is the concept of my proj.. but wen i implemented the half of it, that is insert, delete, download, my mam is laughing on my proj.. that it is not cloud at all.. I dono how to implement it really..

Comment: what could service are you considering ??